# timeout as a condition

Tags: bash, snmp

I'm trying to poll a group of devices with multiple SNMP community strings with a bash script. The goal is that if the snmpwalk times out it trys another string but my condition is erroring.

```
while read line
        do
                ip="$line"
                device=$(/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c string1 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1)
                if [ $device = false ]
                        then
                        device=$(/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c string2 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1)
                        if [ $device = false ]
                                then
                                device=$(/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c string3 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1)
                                break
                        fi
                fi
                echo "$ip $device"
        done < ip-list > device-type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using `-z` and added `timeout -s KILL 2` because it takes so long.

```
while read line
    do
        ip="$line"
        device=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c string1 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1)
            if [ -z "$device" ]
                        then
                        device=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c string2 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1)
                        if [ -z "$device" ]
                                then
                                device=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c string3 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1)
                                if [ -z "$device" ]
                                        then
                                        device=$(echo " Not my problem ")
                                fi
                        fi
                fi
    echo "$ip $device"
    done < ip-list > device-list
```